# Ruby on Rails allow mass assignment for an RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm testing my Rails application with RSpec, but then I ran into a problem. I want a consistent database, therefore I imposed a constraint that some columns can not be null.

I have a Comment model and a comment may be an answer to another comment. Morevoer a comment has an IP address which should not be null. This is the migration:

```
create_table :comments do |t|
  t.string :name, :limit => 20, :null => false
  t.string :comment, :limit => 8192, :null => false
  t.string :ip, :null => false
  t.integer :answer_to_comment_id
end
```

Then I created a `Comment` model with only `name` and `comment` accessible

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :comment

  belongs_to :answer_to, :class_name => "Comment", 
                         :foreign_key => "answer_to_comment_id"

  has_many :answers, :class_name => "Comment", 
                     :foreign_key => "answer_to_comment_id", 
                     :dependent => :destroy
end
```

My `factories.rb` looks like this:

```
Factory.define :comment do |comment|
  comment.name    "test"
  comment.comment "test"  
  comment.ip      "0.0.0.0"
end
```

Now I have the following problem in the RSpec test `comment_spec.rb`

```
describe "some test" do
  before(:each) do
    @answer = @comment.answers.create(Factory.attributes_for(:comment))
  end
end
```

This will fail, because `:ip` is not in the `attr_accessible` list and therefore ActiveRecord can't create the record in the database. I could add `:ip` to the list, but this may cause some security issues because of mass assignment. Or I could add the `:ip` manually, but this could become a lot of work if there were more attributes like `ip`

So I look for a possibility to bypass the `attr_accessible` list. Or if you have a better design pattern, please let me know

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
describe "some test" do
  before(:each) do
    @answer = @comment.answers << Factory(:comment)
  end
end
```

or if you need more than one comment, say `n`

```
describe "some test" do
  before(:each) do
    @answer = @comment.answers = FactoryGirl.create_list(:comment, n)
  end
end
```

Comment: I've found out that the `@comment.answers<<` method returns an array, therefore this solution works for me:

    @comment.answers << (@answer = Factory.build(:comment))

Again, thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this question while searching for a solution to the same problem. I know it's very old, but for what it's worth I dug through the code and decided to solve the problem this way:

```
before :each do
  ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::WhiteList.any_instance.stub(:deny?).and_return(false)
end
```

Perhaps this will come in handy to someone else who winds up here.

Answer (score 0):

I basically use a variation of [this](http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/10/bypassing-attr_accessible-and-attr_protected-for-test-factories) (along with a few other tweak) during testing.

(But Fabio's answer is cleaner--that's one of the things factories are for, making things--not just a holder for attributes :)